# how to display and int with a write function in C

Tags: c

my school has tasked me with printing out a number using the write function. unfortunately
it seems to be way harder than just outputting a string. my current code is as follows:

```c
#include <unistd.h>

// Function to display an integer using write
void displayInt(int num) {
    

    write(1, &num, 2);
}
int main() {
    int number = 42;

    displayInt(number);

    return 0;
}
```

I've tried looking up how to convert an int into a string but i don't think that is the task although i could be wrong. I'm also aware i could just use the ascii tab but that be impractical for higher numbers. can anyone help?

Comment: Convert number to string. Print string.

Comment: ok i will, can you point me into the right direction though?

Comment: yea were not allowed to use the itoa() function, so my guess is to just code the function ourselfs

Comment: The duplicate question has a wide selection of other answers including some great overkill ones capable of doing other bases besides 10.